# Proguard error when using FirebaseRemoteConfig and Play Services SDK

Tags: android, firebase, proguard, android-proguard, firebase-remote-config

When I generate my APK with the following proguard rules

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**

-keep public class com.google.firebase.* {public *;}
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.**
```

I get this error

> Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:   Class       =
>   [com/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig]   Method
>   = [getInstance()Lcom/google/firebase/remoteconfig/FirebaseRemoteConfig;]
>   Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common
>   super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzama] (with 2 known
>   super classes) and [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzamb$zzc] (with 1
>   known super classes))
>
> Warning: Exception while processing task java.io.IOException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of
>   [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzama] (with 2 known super classes)
>   and [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzamb$zzc] (with 1 known super
>   classes)

I found this URL http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#superclass which says me to add the missing class. I am not sure which is the missing class here. Any inputs would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue. it was because I had not updated the version of firebase once i updated google pay services in my gradle. Make sure that the version of your play service sdk and firebase sdk is same